# Random numbers generated show periodicity

Tags: random, fortran

I am trying to generate a sequence of random numbers $\xi_i$ uniformly distributed in [0,1] using the built-in functions in Fortran. The sequence has to be reproducible so I want to seed the random number generator by the index $i$ (that is the position of $\xi_i$ in the sequence) rather than using the system clock for the seed. Below is my code:

```
module rand

contains

  function generate_random(iseed) result(xi1)
  !!
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: iseed

  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: seed
  integer :: i, j, n
  real :: xi1

  !!-generate a seed first
  call random_seed(size = n)
  allocate(seed(n))
  seed = iseed * (/(i, i=1,n,1)/)
  call random_seed(PUT = seed)
  deallocate(seed)

  call random_number(xi1)

  !!
end function generate_random

end module rand

program test

  use rand
  implicit none
  integer :: i, imax

  imax=100

  do i=1,imax
     print *, generate_random(i)
  enddo

end program test
```

However the result of this shown in the plot where $\xi_i$ is plotted vs. the index $i$ clearly has some pattern, so it is not so random after all. How to improve this, i.e., to make it "more random"?

[image]

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  You should read its documentation (if provided) on the use of the seed.  At a guess, there are a lot of zero bits in the seed you provide which won't be good for entropy.

Comment: I agree, you can't just use any number you like as a seed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you are seeding the generator before **every** call to `random_number`. This is a clear abuse and you are not supposed to do that!

You should seed the generator just **once** using some repeatable, but not too simple, number. Even when the clock is used as a seed it is used only once.

Often there is an additional step to increase the entropy of your time or your selected repeatable seed value. Notice how `lcg()` is used to increase entropy of the clock value in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED

Comment: Yes, when I seed the pseudo-random-number-generator (PRNG) only once and then call PRNG a number of times then the resulting distribution does not have these correlated patterns. Now I realize that since PRNG works recursively there is no way to find the k-th number in sequence without calling PRNG k times. Thanks.